# Change position of current gameObject in C# on condition

Tags: c#, position, unity-game-engine, transform

I have been searching and racking my brains for a while now to try and get this code working, to no avail. Hopefully you guys can help.
I have a simple set up with a cube that moves position every frame. I need the cube to go to an x position when it reaches a different location.

Example: Cube starts at position 0, moves forward in the x axis until it gets to position 15, then reverts back to 0 and stops.

```
Vector3 startingPosition;

void Start ()
{
    startingPosition = gameObject.transform.position;
}

void Update ()
{
    if (gameObject.transform.position.x == 15) {
        gameObject.transform.position = startingPosition;

    } else {
        float translation = Time.deltaTime * 2;
        transform.Translate (0, 0, translation);
        transform.Translate (Vector3.forward * translation);
    }
}
```

}

Currently the cube continuously moves (no stopping point), it's x position having no affect on the positioning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `==` to `>=` and see if that makes a difference. My guess is that `position.x` is never *exactly* equal to 15, either due to floating-point precision errors or due to your translation logic skipping over 15 from one frame to the next.

Comment: Ah something so simple! That seems to have worked, brilliant. How would I get the cube to actually stop at starting position though? They now go back to position 0 and start moving forward again.

Comment: @Sandeep When you move it back to its starting position, set a `bool` flag, and then check that flag before you call `Translate()`.

Comment: Very helpful thank you! I will now try to get the cubes translating to an offscreen location, only to be spawned as one other is transferred away! :)

Answer (score 0):

I have had an issue with a animation not working correctly and feel like I have scoured the internet for days trying to get it to work, so this was very helpful. In my situation, the animations' GameObject was at a position of y=1 and should have moved to y=9, but would not update unless I clicked the transition in the animator. I changed the code from `x == 15` to `y <= 9` and `Vector3.forward` to `Vector3.up` and it works perfectly now. Hope this might help someone else with the same issue. using Unity v 2017.1.2